# Remove step line points

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I would like to remove step line points, how to do it?

My code:
http://360.art.pl/krotnica_pcm/przebiegi.html

[image: Point marked with red arrow]

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the body of the question. And feel free to elaborate a bit.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this to turn off points:

```
plotOptions: {
  line: {
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}
```